# For each obj as Object in list.FindAll()

Tags: .net, vb.net

Just wondering if I have this code :

```
Dim listOfStuff As List(Of Stuff) = doSomething()
For each obj as Stuff in listOfStuff
    ...
Next
```

Can I write this instead without affecting memory usage and performance?

```
For each obj as Stuff in doSomething()
    ...
Next
```

And what about this :

```
Dim listOfStuff As List(Of Stuff) = doSomething()
For each obj as Stuff in listOfStuff.FindAll(function(t) ...)
    ...
Next
```

Thanks!

Comment: Define affecting memory usage and performance? I'm guessing you mean you don't want to negatively affect it?

Comment: May want to post this over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Each solution seems valid to me. The last one doesn't seem to be very pertinent though.

Comment: Also you have c# flagged but have listed VB code

Comment: all equal. About `FindAll`, `Where` its more efficient because of his lazy nature.

Comment: I assume you want to know if `doSomething()` `FindAll` and  will run for each iteration?

Comment: Effectively, I don't want to affect negatively memory usage and/or performance.

Comment: Magnus : Yes that is what I'm wondering!

Comment: PseudoNym : Yeah I listed vb.net code but was wondering the same for c#.

Comment: @MathieuG it sounds like you are chasing ghosts here, friend. You really shouldn't have to worry about the extra overhead involved in creating an additional reference pointer. The impact is beyond unsignificant.

Comment: @Crono Just wondering, for having better knowledge, writing better code and cleaner code! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the first alternative without hurting memory or performance. The second alternative will create a new list. This will have a *very low* impact on memory use (typically to the point of being irrelevant), because while you are creating a new list, this list only needs to store object *references*, and not the full objects. To get back to parity with the original, I would suggest `.Where()` instead of `.FindAll()`:

```
For each obj as Stuff in doSomething().Where(Function(t) ...)
    '...
Next
```

You can also *improve* memory use (and usually performance) by modifying your `doSomething()` method (and everything upstream of it) to return and work with `IEnumerable(Of Stuff)` instead of a `List(Of Stuff)`, such that you only need to hold one item in memory at a time, rather than the entire collection.

Comment: The `IEnumerable` suggestion is only good if you only need to iterate the collection once.

Comment: @Magnus depending on the source, you can iterate IEnumerable's more than once by call .Reset().

Comment: Any underlying linq query would be evaluated every time the `IEnumerable` is iterated.

Comment: That's why you typically keep pushing IEnumerables are far as possible (all the way to the presentation tier, if you can manage it), such that IEnumerable for a particular view only needs to be called once.